# Cannot have separate declaration and implementation of class with custom variadic non-template parameters

Tags: c++, clang, variadic-templates, non-type-template-parameter

Is this a bug in Clang (the default version used by Xcode 14)?  The following code does not compile:

```
        struct TestValue
        {

        };
    
        template<TestValue... Values>
        struct TestCompiler
        {
            TestCompiler();
        };
    
        template<TestValue... Values>
        TestCompiler<Values...>::TestCompiler()
        {
            
        }
```

The error message is:

> nested name specifier 'TestCompiler<Values...>::' for declaration does not refer into a class, class template or class template partial specialization

To reproduce this, it's necessary to have the template parameters of `TestCompiler` be non-template types, variadic, and custom (not built in) types.  Defining the class inline compiles, it's only trying to declare and implement the class separately that fails.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I can't see anything wrong with it (assuming C++20 or later) and both GCC and MSVC are fine with it. Only Clang complains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [clang bug](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58250) since the program is well-formed as this is the correct way of providing an out of class definition for a nontemplate ctor of a class template.

Here is the clang bug report:

[Clang rejects valid out of class definition of a nontemplate constructor of a class template](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58250)